# Interpretation of "Mockingbird" by Charles Bukowski

Tags: poetry, interpretation, charles-bukowski

This is the poem "Mockingbird" by Charles Bukowski, first published in *Mockingbird Wish Me Luck* (1972):

> the mockingbird had been following the cat
> all summer
> mocking mocking mocking
> teasing and cocksure;
> the cat crawled under rockers on porches
> tail flashing
> and said something angry to the mockingbird
> which I didn’t understand.
>
> yesterday the cat walked calmly up the driveway
> with the mockingbird alive in its mouth,
> wings fanned, beautiful wings fanned and flopping,
> feathers parted like a woman’s legs,
> and the bird was no longer mocking,
> it was asking, it was praying
> but the cat
> striding down through centuries
> would not listen.
>
> I saw it crawl under a yellow car
> with the bird
> to bargain it to another place.
>
> summer was over.

What is this poem about? Should we take it literally, or is there also a symbolic or metaphorical meaning? What are we to make of the comparison, "feathers parted like a woman’s legs"? Why is the cat "striding down through centuries"? What is the sense of "bargain" in "bargain it to another place"?

Comment: What do you want us to explain?

Comment: Please don't post the full text of copyrighted poems. Include only the parts that you are asking a question about. If necessary, you can include a link to an online version (e.g. on [Genius.com](https://genius.com/Charles-bukowski-the-mockingbird-annotated) or [Poeticous](https://www.poeticous.com/charles-bukowski/the-mockingbird)).